# Text to resize with CSS shape

Tags: html, css

I have some text inside a parallelogram, the problem is that when I resize the window the text loses all its properties, I have tried vw, vh, em, pt, rem and px
Also I have tried with @media screen and (min-width: 320px;)
But nothings seems to work, currently this is what I have so far, I hope you could help me.

```css
.paralelo {
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    padding-left: 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 48%;
    height: 50%;
    max-height: 10px;
    border-top: 50px solid #c5027f;
    border-right: 30px solid #FFf;
}

 .who { 
    font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -21.5%;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="paralelo">
    <p class="who">Servicios</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with using `position` like:

```css
.paralelo {
  position: relative; /* -- add this line */

  margin-top: 8%;
  margin-left: 0%;
  padding-left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  width: 48%;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 10px;
  border-top: 50px solid #c5027f;
  border-right: 30px solid #FFf;
}

.who { 
  position: absolute; /* -- add this line */
  top: -100px; /* -- add this line */
  right: 12px; /* -- add this line */
  
  font-family: "Montserrat","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: white;

  /* margin-top: -21.5%; -- remove this line */
  /* margin-right: 12px; -- remove this line */
}
```

```html
<div class="paralelo">
    <p class="who">Servicios</p>
</div>
```

[here is jsfiddle so you can resize screen](https://jsfiddle.net/5x7p6fsr/)

[read more about how to use position here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

**Update after comment**

Here is the example with `vw` so if you resize the screen it will change all sizes accordingly https://jsfiddle.net/5x7p6fsr/1/

Comment: Hi! thank you for taking the time to answer this, now the problem is that the text doesn't resize with the screen, it stays the same size, no matter if I use vw, rem, px... but it was very helpfull, thank you so much :D

Comment: @CarmenAmaro that's really strange, cause if I try with `vw` it just works ..  https://jsfiddle.net/5x7p6fsr/1/ :)

Comment: yeah maybe is some extra class on my code, I'll check it, thank u again :)